Random spaces in Jetpack Compose
While working on a composable function with Jetpack Compose, I can see that some elements have random extra spaces added to it. It seems that
the IconButton has this extra padding. Can't figure out why it's happening.
See:

My code:
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(
                top = padding.calculateTopPadding(),
                bottom = padding.calculateBottomPadding()
            )
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = Spacing.m, vertical = 0.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Browse",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(0.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,

                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                ),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
            )

            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.FilterAltOff,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.filters)
                )
            }
        }
    }

There are no other components so far and modifier passed from the containing function should not have any influence on this Row.

That spacing is to ensure min touch target size.

Actually that's not what I am talking about. The space you're referring to is the space around the icon. I am trying to get rid of the space outside the button, on top, not inside it.

Still, it is due to min touch target. you will not face this problem if you replace IconButton with any other non-clickable component. this padding is added in the source code of IconButton and you cannot control it as there is no modifier parameter to IconButton.

if you still want to remove this padding, a work around would be to add .minimumInteractiveComponentSize() to modifier of your Text.

@shadox: Would you accept that as an answer? It explains where the padding comes from and why it is needed.

I stand corrected - .minimumInteractiveComponentSize() on the Text did do the trick. There is 0 (zero) logic in this but it works. Weirdly enough, it is the correct answer.

@dev.tejasb if you post it as an answer I'll accept it and then I'll continue to rant about Google's usual consistency... oh boy! :D

sure, I'll add.

@Leviathan I was expecting it to be equally distributed around the IconButton but no...

Space is distributed equally, it's just those confusing lines in preview. @shadox

That spacing is to ensure min touch target size.
You will not face this problem if you replace IconButton with any other non-clickable component. This padding is added in the source code of IconButton and you cannot control it as there is no modifier parameter to IconButton.
If you still want to remove this padding, a work around would be to add .minimumInteractiveComponentSize() to modifier of your Text.

In the end I have sorted it in a different manner but will investigate how come this happens. Why the space is created in such irregular way. Thanks for the suggestion.
